# vertically centring div inside parent div - relative position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the proper way to vertically center a div inside its parent div, if both are position:relative?

my HTML

```
<article>
<div class="row">

    <div class="text-cell">
        <div class="text-content"><h1>text</h1></div>
    </div>

</div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.text-cell {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

wanting 'text-cell' centred in article. ('row' is Bootstrap 3 framework)

Comment: Can you please make sure your html code is correct. You have some unclosed elements (<div class="text-content">).

Comment: <div class="text-content">text</h1>?

Comment: my apologies, i removed php code to make it simpler to illustrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display: inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/kk61saw3/

```css
article {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.text-cell {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*min-height: 50px;*/
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
<div class="row">

    <div class="text-cell">
        <div class="text-content"><h1>text</h1></div>
    </div>

</div>
</article>
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. I want the 'text-cell' div vertically centred in article. Your fiddle centres the text inside text-cell

Comment: the height is unknown in article, the code I provided are the only known values