# vertically centring relative position + unknown height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns in my WP site. One has text/content the other a background image. Both are relatively positioned and the heights are unknown.

HTML (using twitter - bootstrap 3 markup )

```
<article>

  <div id="...removed php code ">

      <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-8 indx-img" style="background-image:url('...');">
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-4 text-cell">
           <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
           <h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
         </div>      

      </div><!-- /row --> 

</article>
```

CSS

```
.indx-img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 16% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.text-cell {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I want the `text-cell` div to be vertically centered in its column. The height of the column is set by its adjacent column `index-img` div with the `padding: 15% 0`

Comment: look into flexbox and `display:table`

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertically centring div inside parent div - relative position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198628/vertically-centring-div-inside-parent-div-relative-position)

Comment: it is a duplicate of sorts, I have changed my code though but still can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

you can fiddle around with the transform translate percentage and a margin-top percentage..something like (play with x and y number to get desired result)

```
.text-cell {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: x% 0 0;
  transform: translateY(y%)
}
```

or figure out the row height in jquery and then set offsets for that `.text-cell` div in jquery

Comment: adding and changing those values didn't effect my div it seems

Answer (score 0):

Add this style :

```
.text-cell {
     display     : flex; 
     align-self  : center;
}
```